# grep, ignoring the last line of the file if it does not have a newline

Tags: bash, sed, grep, newline

When `grep`ing through files that are still being created by other processes, the final line is often incomplete and doesn't yet have a newline at the end. Is it possible with `grep` (or some alternative like `sed`), to ignore this line?

I don't want to just automatically always ignore the last line, because the final line will be valid when the full has been fully created and the final newline has been appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This perl will delete the last line if the file does not end with a newline

```
perl -pe 's/.*// if eof && !/\n/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the file ends with a newline or not with `tail` and `wc`. Remove the last line with `head` if it does not:

```bash
if [[ $(tail -c1 infile | wc -l) != 1 ]]; then 
    mv infile infile.tmp
    head -n-1 infile.tmp > infile
fi
```